# XML validation to require an element if another is not provided - without XSD 1.1

Tags: xml, xsd, xsd-validation

Preferably without using XSD 1.1 - require an XML element if another is not provided and vice versa.

Say I have a Job element:

```
<Job>
  <Ref>""</JobReferenceId>
  <Title>""</JobTitle>
  <Type>""</Type>
  <Contract>""</Contract>
</Job>
```

`Type` should be a required element if `Contract` is not provided and `Contract` should be a required element if `Type` is not provided. Both shouldn't be provided together.

Can I do this without XSD 1.1?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sounds like a straightforward `xs:choice`:

```
xs:sequence
  xs:element name="Ref"
  xs:element name="Title"
  xs:choice
     xs:element name="Type"
     xs:element name="Contract"
```

Comment: Husah! Didn't even know about `xs:choice`! Thank you kind sir!

Comment: I hope you will now do a little bit of reading to find out about the capabilities of the language.